# datepicker dont open the calendar in jsp

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, jsp, datepicker

I'm using the jQuery datepicker for view a calendar on my page.

I imported the libraries in the correct order but it doesn't work.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page language="java"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#fecha").datepicker();
        });
        </script>
        <style>
            .tabla{
                width: 80%;
            }
            .thCliente{
                font-family:sans-serif;
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: bolder;
                background: cadetblue;
            }
            .tdCliente{
              font-family:sans-serif;
              font-size: 14px;
              background: beige;
              align-content: stretch;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="cliente" border="1" class="tabla">
            <form  method="get" action="generaReporte" id="forminicio">
            <tr><th class="thCliente">Febrero</th></tr>
            <th class="thCliente">Fecha </th>
            <th class="thCliente">Cliente</th>
            <th class="thCliente">Actividad</th>
            <th class="thCliente">Horas</th>
<tr>
    <th>
    <input id="fecha" type="text">
    </th>
    <th>    
            <%//establecemos la conexion a la BD para mostrar los clientes
            try
            {
                Connection conexion = null; 
                Statement sentencia = null;
                ResultSet resultado = null;
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                String cadenaConexion = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/LOGIN";
                String usuario = "root";
                String clave = "5533834712";
                conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(cadenaConexion,usuario,clave);
                if(!conexion.isClosed())
                {
                    sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
                    resultado = sentencia.executeQuery("select * from cliente");
                    out.println("<select style='width:300px;border:1px;font-family:sans-serif;font-size: 16px;' name='select'>");
                    out.println("<option >Selecciona el Cliente</option>");
                    while(resultado.next())
                    {
                     String nombre = resultado.getString("Nombre");
                     //String id = resultado.getString("id");
                     out.println("<option value='"+nombre+"'></option>");
                    }
                    out.println("</select>");
                    conexion.close();
                }
                else
                    out.println("fallo");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                out.println("Error"+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            %>
    </th>
    <th>
        <input type="text" style="width:300px;border:1px;font-family:sans-serif;font-size: 16px;" value="Agregar tu Actividad" name="actividad">
    </th>
    <th>
        <input type="text" maxlength="4" style="width:300px;border:1px;font-family:sans-serif;font-size: 16px;" value="Añade tu tiempo" name="actividad">
    </th>
        <th>
        <input type="button" value="Guardar" name="save">
    </th>
</tr>
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes normal jQuery date picker going wrong and not giving the proper output. I'm used to this. A great date picker using the standard jQuery date picker. And you can customized this a bit more than normal date picker. And a good documentation too. This worked well with my jsp pages.

[Get the new custom jQuery datepicker from here](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine check https://jsfiddle.net/5h5vb0nj/. You are mission table close tag

```
 </th>
</tr>   ***</table>***
            </form>
        </body>
```

If problem still persist then remove scriptlet and check if it works now. If iot works means there is an error in scriptlet.

Comment: i made a similar script in other jsp and it works, but in this jsp dont work, i dont know what happen